# Video always looping in VideoJs

Tags: video.js

I am using VideoJS to play the video and it plays well without any issue.

But the video keeps on looping which I don't want. It does not stop after playing once. I have not provided any options for the video to play in loop; but it does.

I even tried adding data-setup with loop as false.

```
<video id="video5" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="500" height="400" data-setup='{ "loop" : "false" }' >
    <source src="http://localhost/~~video(4).mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" />
</video>
```

I am using version 4.5.2 which is the latest build.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is pretty much what I said on the repo issue, but I can't for the life of me reproduce this without specifying a loop option in VJS or the video element. Have you written any other JS that's interacting with the VJS api?

Comment: Actually there is no other codes related to VJS. I am still trying to find out whats making this happen.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this consistently? A live example would go a long way for helping debug...This [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/axedog/999/edit) already has everything you need to get started.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue in JSBin.. but it happens every time in my localhost and in live website of my users. I will share a link after getting a public access page.

Comment: Any chance you've had the time to set up a public page we can take a look at? If you're not able to reproduce on JSBin, I have a feeling this is not VJS-specific issue, but it's hard to tell without an example :)

Comment: Hi, I have asked for the user to share a public url as the site is a private network. I will get back when I get the public url.